# What is the variable's format in the return value?

Tags: php, syntax, return

I am a new learner in php. I found that there is a code:

```
if($x < time()){
     return [false,'error'];
}
```

The logic or variable is not matter, but I don't understand how [false,'error'] works. Is it a boolean or array or ..... ?

Comment: It returns an array first element Boolean and second element String. But remember that return works on a function.

Comment: Thanks for yr response, and I am doing unit test in php. May I ask that is it possible to directly compare an array with an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array.
It has two elements of different two types.
The first element type is boolean.
The second element is a string.

Arrays can have elements of different types in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for yr response, and I am doing unit test in php. May I ask that is it possible to directly compare an array with an array?

Comment: You can compare two arrays with the function array_diff($arr1, $arr2) like:
if(array_diff($arr1, $arr2) == []) { ... something you want the code to do if the arrays are equal ... }